# How to display data in line by line in django

Tags: django

I am building a application in django. In my website I want to use "ping" command  and show the result to view in line by line into textarea. For example: If I ping google then I will receive

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.221.238] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 216.58.221.238: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=52

Reply from 216.58.221.238: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=52

Reply from 216.58.221.238: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=52

Reply from 216.58.221.238: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=52
```

in line by line

How can I show the result in line by line to html page?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you'll need to use AJAX.  You will need:

1) The regular Django view that returns the HTML page:

```
def main_page_view(request):
    return render('main_page.html')
```

2) another Django view that gets the ping status from somewhere and returns it as text or preferably JSON  (you can use `JsonResponse` for this):

```
def ping_status_view(request):
    ping_status_string = get_ping_status()  # Of course you'll have to make this function
    return JsonResponse({'status': ping_status_string})
```

3) some Javascript code on the HTML page that uses AJAX to connect to the URL you've given for your JSON view, gets the JSON, and adds it to the page.  You'll want to use jQuery or another framework, don't try to do AJAX in plain javascript, it's horrible.  jQuery has a [getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method that may be helpful:

```
$.getJson('url.to.django/ping/status/view', function(data){
    var status = data.status
    $("#status-area").append('<p>' + status + '</p>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need get de output of ping using subprocess.

**views.py**

```
def ping(request, url):

from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["ping", "-c 4", url])
out = str(out)
final = out.split('\\n')

return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'ping_out': final})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
url(r'^ping/(?P<url>[\w.@+-/]+)/$', views.ping, name='ping')
```

**my_template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>
    {% for i in ping_out %}
     {{ i }} 
  {% endfor %}
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: linebreaks print]